# TFS 2015 Copy Template URL dropping value

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Using TFS 2015 we have several custom fields on a PBI work item. 
These fields are type Int and have ALLOWEDVALUES rule of zero (0) to five (5). 
When I try to create a template by creating a new template by clicking on the Copy Template URL and the value of the custom field is zero the resulting url contains:

&%5BMyCompany.MinorRelease%5D=

If I set it to any other allowed value I get:

&%5BMycompany.MinorRelease%5D=2

Is there a way to make the valid value of Zero appear?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the behavior too and have helped you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect. You can track it here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1957055

And following are the workaround to this:

a). Since only the value "0" cannot appear in the URL, you can define a DEFAULT value "0" for the field, then the field value will be filled with "0" by default when you create the work item (The parameter will not appear in the URL when the field value matches default value.). And when you create a template URL with other values specified, the URL can show these values correctly.

b). The created URL is editable, you can add the value "0" behind "&%5BMyCompany.MinorRelease%5D=" manually and then share the updated URL to your team.